# If f(x) is continuous on $[a,b],$ differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f'(x)\neq 0\ \forall x\in(a,b),$ then f'(x) is stable.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f'(x)\neq 0\ \forall x\in(a,b)$ then $f'(x)$ is stable $\left(\text{i.e.},\ f'(x)<0\ \  \text{or}\ \  f'(x)>0\right).$

I don't know what to do here using calculus I level only. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29)

Comment: $f'(x)$ is NOT a continious function

Comment: Don't we need $f'$ to be differentiable on $(a,b)$ as well?

Comment: @Bonnaduck No ?

Comment: By stable, you mean $f'$ is exclusively strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on $(a,b)$, correct?

Comment: @user180321 Darboux theorem has not "$f'$ continuous" in its hypotesis.

Answer (score 3):

By [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) the derivative of a real function on an interval has the property of the intermediate value theorem, so if $\;f'(x_0)<0\;$ and $\;f'(x_1)>0\;$ , there's a point $\;c\;$ between $\;x_0,\,x_1\;$ with $\;f'(c)=0\;$ .

Comment: $f'$ is NOT a continious function

Comment: @user180321 I know...and I don't care: Darboux theorem is equaly true. If $\;f'\;$ was continuous then we wouldn't need this theorem, right?

Comment: Is darboux theorem equivalent to Bolzano ?

Comment: @user180321 I've no idea what Bolzano theorem are you talking about, but very probably not. This is a rather well known theorem...did you read the link I posted?

Comment: yes but it holds only if $f$ is  continuous on $[a,b].$ We don't know if $f'$ is continuous function. What do you mean "I don't care " ?

Comment: @user180321 Will you *please* read the link I posted?! Or, at least, google "Darboux Theorem". It says that *any* function which is the derivative of another function has the intermediate value property, meaning: the image of an interval is an interval, again. If the derivative was continuous we **would not need** this beautiful theorem. would we?. What amazes is that it is true *even* if the derivative isn't continuous!